# Loading a partial view into a DIV element dynamically is replacing the entire DOM vs the element

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Within a view I am trying to load a partial view from the controller. I am using the `Ajax.ActionLink` method to make this call

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Involved Entities/Resources", 
                 "GetNarratives", 
                 new { id = 4 }, 
                 new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET",  
                 UpdateTargetId = "narrContainer" })
```

Further down in the page I have a div element with the id of `narrContainer`

```
<div id="narratives" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseNarrative">Narratives [ @Model.AssociatedNarrative.Count() ]</a></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseNarrative" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div id="narrContainer"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The controller has the following code:

```
   public PartialViewResult GetNFIRNarratives(string id)
            {
                //Get Narratives 
                fauxModel fm = new fauxtModel();
                List<Narrative> narr = new List<Narrative>();
                narr = fm.GenerateMockBaseNarratives(4);

                return PartialView("_myAssociatedNarrative", narr);
            }
```

The partial view contains fields for the collection:

```
<!-- Assocaited Narrative-->
@for (int i = 0; i < @Model.Count(); i++)
{
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <p><strong>Date Entered</strong>&nbsp; @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].DateEntered)</p>
    </div>
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(@Model[i].Title))
    {
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p><strong>Narrative Title</strong>&nbsp; @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Title)  </p>
        </div>
    }
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <p>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].NarrativeText)</p>
        <hr />
    </div>

}
```

Within the base layout page I have added reference to the unobtrusive-ajax script as

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/js/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And I have confirmed that the key is enabled in the web.config file.

```
 <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

When I click on the link to load the narratives the code executes but it does not load the partial in the div element. Instead it is replacing the current view the partial. What I am missing that is causing the partial to be loaded /replacing the current document and what do I need to change to get the partial to render only within the specified div element?

Answer (score 0):

After working through the Post Event more I discovered that the `@Ajax.Action` was not posting as an AJAX call. This was the result of the jquery-unobtrusive-ajax.js file being outdated and containing deprecated jquery functions (`.live()`) .

I updated the files through NuGet using

```
Install-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax
```

and the actions are now working correctly.